# How to make sphinx specify full module path for documented parameters?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, autodoc

I'm using sphinx to auto document a class. The constructor looks something like this:

```py
from PyQt6.QtCore import QEasingCurve

class MyClass:
    def __init__(animationType=QEasingCurve.Type.OutCubic):
        # constructor function
```

When I generate the docs for this class, the `animationType` parameter is documented like this:

[image]

I don't want it to specify only half the path like this. I want it to say `animationType=PyQt6.QtCore.Qt.QEasingCurve.Type`. How can I do this?

This is what my reStructuredText source file looks like:

```
MyClass
=======

.. automodule:: MyModule.MyClass
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

Answer (score 1):

Just import PyQt6 and use `PyQt6.QtCore.Qt.QEasingCurve.Type` in your code